# Can Xamarin.Forms work on IPhone (real device) via Wi-FI without connection to real Mac Os From VS 2019 CE Windows 10?

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, xamarin

I have:

- iPhone SE.
- Windows 10 Pro x64
- VS 2019 CE
- MacBook

Is there a way to run and debug my Xamarin.Forms app on my iPhone SE via Wi-Fi from VS 2019CE (on PC) but without permanent access to my MacBook?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Hot Restart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/deploy-test/hot-restart) feature of `Visual Studio 16.5` and above,and install the `iTunes` on your PC,then you could deploy your Xamarin.Forms iOS app on you Iphone or iPad without using a Mac.

You could look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/deploy-test/hot-restart.

Comment: Thank's, but i need run and debug without Mac and via Wi-Fi...

Comment: @jin15 You don't need a Mac to do this, you just need to install iTunes on your PC and follow the documented steps. Of course there are some limitations , and I don't think you can debug the app over wifi without using a Mac.